# How do you keep a non-debian Linux installation up to date. There is no apt-get on this one

Tags: linux

I manage a Ubuntu server at work that uses the debian system, keeping it up to date is as simple as running apt-get update and apt-get upgrade daily.

I have another server I manage for a customer which is a VPS hosted at 1&1 internet in the USA.  This system uses a PLESK panel system, but I also have root access and can SSH into it.

When I do a uname -a I get:

Linux xxxxxxx.onlinehome-server.com 2.6.27.19rootserver-20090306a #1 SMP Mon Mar 16 05:01:00 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

How do I keep the packages in this system up to date?  Security is an issue on this machine as there is some ecommerce being done on it.

My first goal is to update mySQL from 5.0.95 to the latest version.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the distribution this server runs? What does `/etc/issue` say?

Comment: Maybe try a `cat /proc/version`?

Comment: cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.27.19rootserver-20090306a (root@rpmbuildd-amd64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)) #1 SMP Mon Mar 16 05:01:00 EDT 2009

Comment: /etc/issue:
CentOS release 5.2 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux and uses [yum](http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/yum/) as its package manager.

According to its documentation, you should be able to issue commands like:

```
$ su -c 'yum groupupdate "MySQL Database"'
```

Comment: Silly to close this for those reasons.  Maintaining a server is neccessary information. You have questions here about "why sauron kept the mountain if it was the only place the ring of rings could be destroyed"

Answer (score 2):

What distro is it based on?

Other Linux distros have other package management tools like pacman(for Arch) and yum (for Red Hat). If yours doesn't have any, I guess you could just build the software from source the new versions of software you want to update.

Comment: Yeah but that would suck!!